# Defining an XML element that must be empty or decimal

Tags: xml, xsd, nullable

I have the following XSD which was generated by VS from an example XML file:

```
                <xs:element name="amperage_rating">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:attribute name="unit" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
```

which demands a numeric value. But sometimes the value is not known and this must also be allowed:

```
<amperage_rating unit="A"></amperage_rating>
```

I've tried nillable="true" but it had no effect. I have also tried to define a union with a 0-length string but that keeps saying it is "not supported in this context".

So how do I adjust the XSD to allow this?

Answer (score 4):

You can combine the two types you wish to allow via `xs:union`:

```
<xs:element name="amperage_rating" type="empty_or_decimal"/>

<xs:simpleType name="empty_or_decimal">
  <xs:union memberTypes="empty xs:decimal"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="empty">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value=""/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if your use case is very like some of the motivating cases for xsi:nil.  From your description, it sounds as if you made the element nillable, but then fed it an non-nilled instance of the form

```
<amperage_rating unit="A"></amperage_rating>
```

instead of specifying that the element should be nilled:

```
<amperage_rating unit="A" xsi:nil="true"></amperage_rating>
```

If you want to modify the type, the methods described by kjhughes and Michael Kay should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches. One is what @kjhughes suggests: define a union between `xs:decimal` and a zero-length-string type. The other, which I personally prefer, is to define a list type with item type `xs:decimal` and maxLength 1. Although the effect on validation is exactly the same, I think the list type is easier to use when the schema is used for data typing: certainly with XSLT and XQuery, where atomizing the element will give you a sequence of zero or one decimals.